# How can I deal with CORS issue with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get data from images.google.com with `axios.get` on my create-react-app application and hosting by firebase.

This is the function of getting request results data from the URL.

```
    const getImage = (transcript) => {
        console.log("getImage executed,", transcript[transcript.length-1])
        axios.get(`/images?&um=1&hl=en&nfpr=1&q=${transcript[transcript.length-1]}`)
            .then((res)=> {
                const search = document.querySelector(".search");
                search.innerHTML = res.data;
                search.querySelectorAll("img").forEach((element) => {
                    if(element.hasAttribute("data-src")){
                        const firstImage = element.getAttribute('data-src');
                        images.push(firstImage);
                        setSearchResult(images[images.length-1]);
                    }
                });
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```

and on package.json I added

`"proxy": "https://images.google.com"`

but of course still blocked by CORS.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGErr.png)

I know this is wrong and I think I don't understand the concept of middleware or backend server stuff enough.
So is there any idea to solve this problem in an easy way? Thanks.

Comment: You simple cant, web browser will block those calls. You have to build an API instead and point your calls to the API. The API will handle those calls for you

Comment: @Alen.Toma Thanks for your reply, so which mean is I have to make another project for building an API? if I'm not correct could you explain a little bit?

Comment: Yes you are right. Read here will you understand https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/

Comment: @Alen.Toma Thank you!

Comment: If you are using chrome - there is a CORS plugin you can try. I dont know if it will work in your case tbh but it wont hurt: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Comment: @Delice yeah but the app needs to work on my firebase hosting server too, not only when I developing on the local server. I already tested with that extension app though.